# Python dictionary creation through comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary

For some reason a dictionary I am producing from a list doesnt seem to be adding a new key pair each time but instead just overwritting the same pair. Im pretty sure it probably obvious to many whats wrong here but Im just not seeing it, any help pointed would be appreciated.

Below is the data and code snippets

```
forest_root = 'domain4.co.uk'

domains = ['domain:domain1.co.uk', 'domain:domain2.co.uk', 'domain:domain3.co.uk', 'domain:domain4.co.uk']

dict1 = {forest_root: [dict(domain.split(":", 1) for domain in domains)] }

print dict1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"domain4.co.uk": [{"domain": "domain4.co.uk"}]}
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
{"domain4.co.uk": 
               [
               "domain": "domain4.co.uk",
               "domain": "domain1.co.uk",
               "domain": "domain2.co.uk",
               "domain": "domain3.co.uk",
               ]
}
```

**Post Answer**

Thanks all, I can now see what I was doing wrong and understand how to achieve my expected outcome.

Comment: What would you like the output to be?

Comment: Well, when you split those up in key, value pairs inside the list-comp and put them into a `dict` they all have the same *key* of "domain" - so you only get the last one - what were you expecting?

Comment: Your `for domain in domains` is in the "dictionary comprehension (in `dict(..)`), not in the list comprehension.

Comment: you create the dictionary four times. To add a new element you have to do dict1[new_key] ...

Comment: Id expect it to have a nested dict, example forest_root: domain: domain1.co.uk, domain:domain2.co.uk etc

Comment: Pls edit your question to include the Output

Comment: @A.Joly The dictionary is created only once, it's just that a value is assigned to the same key 4 times (in the inner dict)

Comment: ah, sorry, I didn't understand ... can the OP add the expected output to his question ? this would be clearer ...

Comment: It's pretty clair that you using the same key for all values

Comment: @iNoob please update your question with your desired output.

Comment: Yes I can see its pretty clear, what I am trying to assertain is how was I mean to carry out the task

Comment: That is not logical, and has no meaning

Comment: same key for sevral value, not logic, what the type of output you want

Comment: I can't answer such a illogical question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need a nested dict, like this:

```
forest_root = 'domain4.co.uk'

domains = ['domain:domain1.co.uk', 'domain:domain2.co.uk', 'domain:domain3.co.uk', 'domain:domain4.co.uk']

dict1 = {forest_root: [{d[0]: d[1]} for d in [domain.split(":", 1) for domain in domains]] }

print dict1
```

Output

```
{'domain4.co.uk': [{'domain': 'domain1.co.uk'}, {'domain': 'domain2.co.uk'}, {'domain': 'domain3.co.uk'}, {'domain': 'domain4.co.uk'}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the the inner dictionary is a poor data structure to choose in this case. It is apparent that you require multiple different entries with the same key, which is not possible with dictionaries.

Things you could try:

Inner loop could be tuple pairs:

```
dict1 = {forest_root: [domain.split(":", 1) for domain in domains] }
```

Or creating a dictionary that looks up lists of items corresponding to the same key.

It is not clear which will be better as the choice for these types of things depends on the demands of your use case

Answer (score 0):

why would you want a dictionary where all the keys are the same? dictionaries don't work that way, plus you can't actually *do* anything with that information.

so what you want is something like:

```
{forest_root: [d.split(':', 1)[-1] for d in domains]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forest_root = 'domain4.co.uk'

domains = ['domain:domain1.co.uk', 'domain:domain2.co.uk', 'domain:domain3.co.uk', 'domain:domain4.co.uk']
dict1 = {forest_root: [{domain.split(":", 1)[0]: domain.split(":",1)[1]} for domain in domains]}

print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{'domain4.co.uk': [{'domain': 'domain1.co.uk'}, {'domain': 'domain2.co.uk'}, {'domain': 'domain3.co.uk'}, {'domain': 'domain4.co.uk'}]}
```